# How do i set up a cronjob in mac os that runs every 15 mins

Tags: macos-sierra, cronjob

I have a command that gets the utilization status of my infra and it needs to be run every 15mins. how do I set a cronjob for that in Mac OS. I searched for cron.hourly and cron.weekly but could not locate them in my mac. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS has moved from `cron` towards `launchd` to perform periodical tasks. Try out the [tutorial at alvinalexander.com](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs) to archive your goal.